# How to migrate a single gitlab project to another server?

Tags: git, gitlab, data-migration, gitlab-7

I have two gitlab servers, server A and server B. There are several different projects on these servers.

Notes:

- Server A gitlab version is 7.3.2
- Server B gitlab version is 7.13.5
- there is no network connection between the servers
- To migrate the source code and the wiki should be easy, as both are git-repositories. But what about the issues?

**How can I migrate a single gitlab project (including Issues and Wiki) from server A to server B?**